# fast report causing access denied error in mvc .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, report, fastreport

I created a web application that includes fast report for creating report.

If I run application on my device, everything is alright. But if I upload my project to the host and a user clicks on the **Generate report** button for the first time, the following error is shown:

[image: Screen with server error]
However, if the user refreshes the page or presses the **Back** button and then clicks the **Generate report** button again, everything is alright. So this error only appears for the first time the page loaded. I didn't use the path from above in my code at all.
Can anyone help me to solve this error? I have no Idea where this error come from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. If anyone also has this problem let me know.